# Select between date range and specific time range

Tags: mysql, sql, select, time

Is there a way to Select records between dates and specific time range. For example all the records from 2013-11-01 to 2013-11-30 between hours 05:00 to 15:00. Here what i made until now.

```
    select count(*) as total from tradingaccounts accounts
inner join tradingaccounts_audit audit on audit.parent_id = accounts.id
where date(audit.date_created) between date('2013-11-01 00:00:00') AND date('2013-11-01 23:59:59')
```

But how am I going to set the specific time range?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `HOUR` function to add an additional condition on the hours:

```
select count(*) as total from tradingaccounts accounts
inner join tradingaccounts_audit audit on audit.parent_id = accounts.id
where date(audit.date_created) between date('2013-11-01 00:00:00') AND date('2013-11-01 23:59:59') 
AND HOUR (audit.date_created) BETWEEN 5 AND 15
```

Comment: is there a way to say between hours:mins:secs instead only hour ?

Comment: @user1292656 sure - you can use a `TIME` function. E.g., `TIME(audit.date_created) BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '15:00:00'`.

Answer (score 2):

As others answered, `HOUR()` could help you.

But HOUR() or DATE() cannot use `INDEX`. To make query faster, I suggest that add `time_created TIME` column and save only TIME part. after that `ADD INDEX(date_created, time_created)`. finally with below query, you can retrieve rows with high speed.

```
where audit.date_created between '2013-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-01 23:59:59'
  AND audit.time_created BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '15:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function, it skips time part. Use [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) instead.

Answer (score 0):

add following line in query and set your hour in BETWEEN

and time(audit.date_created) between '00:00:01' AND '01:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

If you use `date(audit.date_created)`, the index on `date_created` field could not take effect.

Just simply use `where audit.date_created >= 'xx-xx-xx' and audit.date_created < 'xx-xx-xx'`